# Проблема с ботом и гпт (gpt) Мне надо делать запрос в гпт

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек, gpt

У меня есть чат бот, мне нужно что бы он отправлял сообщения в гпт и возвращал мне ответ гпт. Как это можно реализовать бесплатно. Библиотеку которую вы используете для решения мне не важна, я подстроюсь. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Бесплатно – никак. APIшка у GPT платная, и навряд ли найдётся что-то бесплатное. Однако можно использовать альтернативы, можно поискать на Hugging Face.

Comment: @ΝNL993 раньше новорегам давали доступ к апи 3.5 вроде(на 3 месяца)

Comment: @Amgarak оно по моему так и осталось. Ну вы ведь понимаете, что $5 (в виде токенов), которые дают по факту на долго не хватит если делать телеграм бота.

Comment: @ΝNL993 одного аккаунта да, а если их нарегать сотню?) прикрутить авторегистрацию/покупку номера, замену исчерпаного токена на новый... И того меняем 30 рублей за номер на 5 баксов

Comment: @Amgarak, там наверняка защите стоит. Если бы все было так просто...

Comment: @Глеб я когда тестировал их апи сжёг с пяток аккаунтов и всё работало штатно, но не стоит рассматривать серьёзно то что я написал выше - это не инструкция, всего-навсего шутка;)

Comment: @Глеб а так если запарится, то можно и без токенов бота поднять. Я делал как, запускал вебдрайвер, логинился в гпт и отправлял запросы в живую, после чего публиковал ответы как новые темы на своём сайте(через бд). Так что думаю можно так и бота поднять "бесплатного". Это конечно не серьёзно, медленно, но делал чисто порофлить  ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем доброго времени суток, спасибо всем пытавшимся помочь! Я к счастью сам справился с этой проблемой. В России Сбер запустил свою чат-гпт под названием ГигаЧат! Её можно использовать на питоне полностью бесплатно! Так же к ней есть документации. Единственно, придётся зарегестрироваться через СберID, но это не сложно и денег с вас не спишут. Пользуйтесь!

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]